# Does anyone know better way to scan for IPMI devices?

Tags: ipmi, nmap, bmc

Iam using a simple nmap scan on IPMI/BMC port 623/tcp.
Is this enough or Is there anything more I need to be aware using nmap?

```
nmap -p 623 IP-IPEND
```

Comment: an open port is not enough. you can use ipmiping/rmcpping in addition to nmap.

Answer (score 0):

Supermicro's ipmiview will find IPMI devices on your network. I am not sure if it will find all devices or not, but it was able to find a TYAN board and a Supermicro board on my network.

Answer (score 0):

Your nmap commands are a good start

```
nmap -n -p 623 10.0.0./24
nmap -n-sU -p 623 10.0.0./24
use  auxiliary/scanner/ipmi/ipmi_version
```